# Change position of mesh

Tags: plotting, mesh

I'm trying to plot a 3D graphic and I want to highlight the intersection between two graphics: a plane and a surface. I thought that `Meshfunction->{#3&}` was a good idea, but I realized that I can't change the position of the mesh!

This is my code:

```
a = 0.5;
J = -3.00;

U[x_,y_,a_] := -(1-a)/Sqrt[(x-a)^2+y^2] - a/Sqrt[(x+1-a)^2+y^2] - 0.5*(x^2+y^2);
t=Table[
  Show[
    Plot3D[2*U[x,y,a], {x,-1.5,1.5}, {y,-1.5,1.5},
           PlotRange -> {-2.7,-4.0}, Mesh -> 1, MeshFunctions -> {#3&}, 
           MeshStyle -> {Orange, Thick}, ClippingStyle->None,
           PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray], 
           AxesLabel -> {Style["x",Italic,20],Style["y",Italic,20],Style["J=2U(x,y,a)",Italic,20]}],
    Plot3D[J-t, {x,-1.5,1.5}, {y,-1.5,1.5}, 
           Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green,Opacity[0.5]]],
    ImageSize->700], 
  {t, 0., .7, .2}]
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
a = 0.5;
J = -3.00;

U[x_, y_, a_] := -((1 - a)/Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + y^2]) - 
   a/Sqrt[(x + 1 - a)^2 + y^2] - 0.5*(x^2 + y^2);
t = Table[
  Show[Plot3D[2*U[x, y, a], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
    PlotRange -> {-2.7, -4.0}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {(#3 - (J - t)) &}, MeshStyle -> {Orange, Thick},
     ClippingStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray], 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Italic, 20], Style["y", Italic, 20], 
      Style["J=2U(x,y,a)", Italic, 20]}], 
   Plot3D[J - t, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, Mesh -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]]], 
   ImageSize -> 700], {t, 0., .7, .2}]
```

[image]

You can have a look at `Mesh` and `MeshFunction` documentation, it's very helpful I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what i need !!!! Very good answer ! Yes i see the MeshFunction documentation but i didn't understand how to modify the simple `MeshFunction->{#3&}` to a dynamic version that change the meshLevel.